# How to show sequential number in php

Tags: php

I would like to create sequential number based on how many data appear from query result.
for example:

- 1- david
- 2- ahmad
- 3- james

---

```
<?
$class_id=$_GET['class_no'];

    $get_st=mysql_query("select * from students where calss_no='".$class_id."'");
    if($get_st != 0) {

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_st)) {

             $st_no=$row['st_no'];
             $st_first_name=$row['st_first_name'];
             $st_last_name=$row['st_last_name'];
             $calss_no=$row['calss_no'];
             $super_no=$row['super_no'];

                echo"<a href=\"st_page.php?st_no=$st_no\">$st_first_name &nbsp;&nbsp;$st_last_name </a>"."<br>";        
        }

    } 
?>
```

Comment: You don't know how to increment a number and add it to the output? Also can't wait to visit `page.php?class_no=some_sql_injection_here`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just give the concept.
this code is not structured.

```
    <?php
    $class_id=$_GET['class_no'];

        $get_st=mysql_query("select * from students where calss_no='".$class_id."'");
        if($get_st != 0) {
         $sn = 1;
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($get_st)) {

                 $st_no=$row['st_no'];
                 $st_first_name=$row['st_first_name'];
                 $st_last_name=$row['st_last_name'];
                 $calss_no=$row['calss_no'];
                 $super_no=$row['super_no'];

                    echo"<a href=\"st_page.php?st_no=$st_no\">$sn - $st_first_name &nbsp;&nbsp;$st_last_name </a>"."<br>"; 
                $sn++       
            }

        }


?>
```